# Error al levanta un projecto springboot en jboss 7.4 Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss-eap

Cree una aplicación en spring tools suite, para correrla en jboss 7.4 pero hasta ahora no he podido, ya busque varias soluciones que encontré y ninguna me ayudo.

intente cambiar y o agregar las dependencias de jakarta servlet pero no me funciona, tambien agregue algunas exclusiones que vi para que no se generara ese error pero no funcionaron

esta es una parte del error:

```
21:05:50,633 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module "deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

21:05:50,633 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module "deployment.demo.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.demo.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

este es mi pom, hasta ahora agregue exclusiones y otras dependencias que vi en otros foros pero no me ayuda, quiza sea mi version de spring? tengo que usar el jboss 7.4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Este es mi dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.2.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.19:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.19:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.19:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.2.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.2.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.12:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.12:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- jakarta.servlet.jsp:jakarta.servlet.jsp-api:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] \- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```